# Телеграм-бот перестал работать

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

После внесения очередных изменений в код телеграм-бота заметил, что он перестал функционировать.

Код Main-функции:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Запущен бот " + bot.GetMeAsync().Result.FirstName); // *

    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationToken = cts.Token;
    var receiverOptions = new ReceiverOptions
    {
        AllowedUpdates = { }, // receive all update types
    };
    bot.StartReceiving(
        HandleUpdateAsync,
        HandleErrorAsync,
        receiverOptions,
        cancellationToken
    );

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Звездочкой помечена строчка, на которой застревает программа, а конкретно - метод `.GetMeAsync()` выполняется бесконечно.

Если игнорировать выполнение этого метода, то при отправке боту сообщения должен срабатывать метод `HandleUpdateAsync`. Однако этого не происходит: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема за пределами показвнного кода, или вообще не в коде.